# 200 different natural numbers to split in sum and products

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

I wonder if there are $n=200$ different natural numbers with the property that the sum (products) of the first $100$ is equal accordingly to the sum (products) of the rest $100$ numbers? How to find the numbers?  There are numbers like $2+8+9=3+4+12=19$  and $2⋅8⋅9=3⋅4⋅12$, but what about  $n>6$?

Comment: By "sum (product)" do you mean sum *and* product?

Comment: @mzp yes, l mean the numbers like 2,8,9,3,4,12 are splitted in sum 2+8+9=3+4+12 and the product: 2•8•9=3•4•12

Comment: You only have two equations in $200$ unknowns.  It should be easy.  Requiring naturals makes it a little harder, but it won't be much.

Comment: An interesting challenge might be to find the set with the lowest maximum value. I might try it for some smaller set size, say $15$ in each group.

Comment: Why have you written $n = 200$ at the top?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Just an example of a big number to find a general solution. Any doubts?

Comment: @Mike Misread the question, thought you were asking for 200 solutions for a value of $n$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you can do it for $n=2m$ numbers, you can do it for $n=2(m+3)$ numbers. Write your answer for $n=2m$ as $a_1,\dots,a_m,b_1,\dots,b_m$.

Choose $k>\max(a_1,\dots,a_m,b_1,\dots b_m)$ and add $a_{m+1}=2k,a_{m+2}=8k, a_{m+3}=9k,$ and $b_{m+1}=3k,b_{m+2}=4k,b_{m+3}=12k.$

Basically, we are adding a scaled version of you $n=3$ answer, picking the scale so that the new numbers are greater than all the previous numbers.

More generally, a solution for $n=2m$ and one for $n'=2m'$ gives a solution for $n''=2(m+m').$

---

We get an answer for $n=8$ with:

$$(2,9,16,18),\\
(3,6,12,24)$$

So you can get a sequence for $n=200$ by adding $6$ new elements to this $32$ times.

Since you can pick $k$ to be a power of $2$, you can actually ensure that your sequence is all numbers of the form $2^i3^j$ where $j\leq 2.$

---

Given solutions for $n=6$ and $n=8$, we can solve for any $n=6a+8b$, for integers $a,b\geq 0.$ This is all even $n\geq 6$ other than $n=10.$

If you can solve for $n=10$, then you have solutions for all even $n\geq 6.$

Here is an answer for $n=10:$

$$(3,4,36,64,72),\\
(2,9,24,48,96)$$

So we preserve our property that we can find such sequences for all even $n\geq 8$ such that the numbers are of the form $2^i3^j$ with $j\leq 2$.

---

Here is how I found the $n=8$ example. The same was used for $n=10.$

First, added $1$ to both sides of the $n=3$ example. Then I multiplied both by $2$, getting:

$$(2,4,16,18),\\(2,6,8,24)$$

Then I added $9$ to both sequences:

$$(2,4,9,16,18),\\(2,6,8,9,24)$$

Then I replaced the $2,8,9$ on the second sequence with $(3,4,12)$ giving:

$$(2,4,9,16,18),\\(3,4,6,12,24)$$

Then I removed the common value $4$ from these two, giving:

$$(2,9,16,18),\\(3,6,12,24)$$

Comment: Thank you! Any sequences like that in oeis.org?

Comment: Not sure which sequence you'd mean would be in OEIS.

Comment: Last step "common value $9$" should be "common value $4$"? with the first 4-tuple adjusted accordingly

Comment: Yes, fixed. Thanks @Joffan

Answer (score 2):

To complement @Thomas Andrews' answer, here is an $n=8$ solution:

$$ \{1,6,7,10\}\quad\text{and}\quad \{2,3,5,14\},$$

and the Matlab code I used to get it (there are many others):

```
r = 14;

for i1 = 1:r
    for i2 = i1+1:r
        for i3 = i2+1:r
            for i4 = i3+1:r
                for j1 = 1:r
                    for j2 = j1+1:r
                        for j3 = j2+1:r
                            for j4 = j3+1:r
                                if((i1 ~= j1) && (i1 ~= j2) && (i1 ~= j3) && (i1 ~= j4))
                                    if((i2 ~= j1) && (i2 ~= j2) && (i2 ~= j3) && (i2 ~= j4))
                                        if((i3 ~= j1) && (i3 ~= j2) && (i3 ~= j3) && (i3 ~= j4))
                                            if((i4 ~= j1) && (i4 ~= j2) && (i4 ~= j3) && (i4 ~= j4))
                                                if((i1+i2+i3+i4 == j1+j2+j3+j4) && (i1*i2*i3*i4 == j1*j2*j3*j4))
                                                    disp([i1,i2,i3,i4,j1,j2,j3,j4])
                                                end
                                            end
                                        end
                                    end
                                end
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I hope I never see this kind of code in production.

Comment: Just a heads up! My professors always emphasised that you should _never_ use loops in MATLAB. Always try to use matrices where possible, as these will be enormously quicker.

Comment: I agree this is not an efficient code. It was just simple and quick to write. @AlexT., the advice to *never* use loops in MATLAB is a bit hyperbolic. Sometimes they are useful.